TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. Вылазит данная ошибка
n = int(input())
str = ''
q = ''
w = ''
p = ''
a = []
k = 0
for i in range(n):
    k = str(int(input()))
    s = s + k + ' '
    
while s != '':
    str = s
    while str != '':
        q = s[:s.find(' ') + 1]
        w = str[:str.find(' ')]
        p = q + w
        a.append(p)
        str = str[str.find(' ') + 1:]
    s = s[s.find(' ') + 1:]

for i in range(len(a) + 1):
    for j in range(len(a) + 1):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            a = a[:j] + a[j + 1:]
print(a, sep='\n')

Вылазит ошибка TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. Лишних скобок нет. Как исправить?

возможные дубликаты

str - тип данных в Python, поэтому его нельзя использовать как название для переменной. На будущее, называйте переменные полными названиями чтобы понимать что к чему.

Не то, чтобы их нельзя использовать. Использовать можно, но потом будут вот такие сюрпризы. Поэтому лучше не использовать. )

Никогда не используйте в качестве имён переменных названия встроенных функций питона.
str = ''
...
for i in range(n):
    k = str(int(input()))

Тут str уже не встроенная функция питона, а ваша переменная с пустой строкой. Что вы тут хотите сделать, вызывая вашу переменную str как функцию, питон не понимает.
